# OneSignal web notifications is shown event when application tab is in focus

Tags: web, onesignal

i'm working on chat application, and using onesignal for web push notifications in chrome.

But issue is that use continue to receive web push notifications event when tab with application is active.

Is there any way to mute onesignal push notifications during application tab is in focus?

Comment: Did you have any luck answering this?  I found some ways to modify service workers per here, but am unclear how to run custom service workers code for onesignal - plus seems like it'd be a common issue... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150642/check-if-window-is-active-from-service-worker